# Storing fetched user info in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, fetch

I have a model "User" calling an API with an ID returning information such as desired pagination, language, role etc.

When I perform a fetch on the model's instance, it works fine. I know I need to wait for the fetch to be finished, but how do I keep the variables I'd potentially define on success callback visible to the rest of application?

```
var user = new App.Models.User();

user.fetch().done(function() {
    //when I define fruit_list here, it's not visible to the outside world
});

// fruit_list view uses the information retrieved from the user model (pagination), which falls into the default because fetch wasn't performed yet

var fruit_list = new App.Views.FruitList();
```

Any thoughts? What is the best practice for storing global user information?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If visibility to outside world is your concern, this can be one option.

You already have a global variable `App` declared for your application. You can create a separate namespace for `model` and `view` instances as well. For e.g.

```
App.models = {
    user : new App.Models.User()
};
App.views = {
    fruit_list : new App.Views.FruitList()
};
App.models.user.fetch().done(function() {
    // do your stuff with 'user' model and 'fruit_list' view
    // App.views.fruit_list
});
```